# htaccess url rewrite, but duplicate content + variable suffix

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking for a simple rewrite or redirect from:

> http://www.example.com/**media-gallery**/1234-abcdef.html

to

> http://www.example.com/**3d-media**/videos/1234-abcdef.html

where **"1234-abcdef.html"** is dynamic suffix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find by myself the solution:

Redirect any link with `???/Media-gallery/???` to `???/3d-media/videos/???`

```
RedirectMatch permanent media-gallery/(.*) http://3dstreaming.org/3d-media/videos/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect any path from media-gallery ending with ".html" you could use regexp.

For example like this:
`RewriteRule ^media-gallery/(.*).html?$ 3d-media/$1.html [NC,L]`

This should match a url starting with media-gallery/ and ending with .html.
the parentheses grab anything that's matched between them and $1 places the first matched pattern (we only have 1 in this case) in the result.

I haven't tested this, though.

If you want to build more complex rules, you can achieve that with regular expressions as well.

Comment: hello, many thanks for your quick answer, I need to any "media-gallery" to "3d-media" without html and plus the variable "1234-abcde.html" as always variable contents, example:

Comment: domain.com/media-gallery/1234-abcde.html
have to domain.com/3d-media-gallery/1234-abcde.html
or
domain.com/media-gallery/9876-zxy.html
have to domain.com/3d-media/9876-zxy.html

I have +1.000 links with 1234.abcde.html / 9876.xyz.html and more more.... hopw you understand me, sorry for my bad English

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the code I posted should do exactly that.

It should redirect media-gallery/x.html to 3d-media/x.html
where x can be anything.